# Why isn't view reflecting updated data from view model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have the following code:

```
        public ViewResult test(testModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    SaveData(model);
            }

            testModel.Name = "testing returned view data";

            return View("TestManage", model);
        }
```

The TestManage view has

```
@model testModel
```

and has the textbox

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
```

Why isn't the view reflecting the new testModel.Name data? Am I missing something or is this part of a bigger problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clear the model state by using `ModelState.Clear()`

```
  public ViewResult test(testModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                SaveData(model);
        }

        testModel.Name = "testing returned view data";

         ModelState.Clear();
        return View("TestManage", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the ModelState ModelState.Clear()
or you can this:

```
     public ViewResult test(testModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                SaveData(model);
        }

        ModelState["Name"].Value = "testing returned view data"; 

        return View("TestManage", model);
    }
```

More details you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848586/asp-net-mvc-ajax-form-if-value-changes-in-model-after-post-form-still-display)